# Flash Error : SecurityError: Error #2000 about socket

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, sockets

```
function SocketExample() 
{
   socket = new Socket();

   // Add an event listener to be notified when the connection
   // is made
   socket.addEventListener( Event.CONNECT, onConnect );

   // Connect to the server
   socket.connect( "127.0.0.1", 2901 );
}

function onConnect( event:Event ):void 
{
  tt.text = "Successful linking";
}
```

I try to connect to Socket by Flash as3.0.
But it's not work,it show me a error "SecurityError: Error #2000".
How do I avoid this error?

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the call to the `connect()` method outside of your constructor and calling it a bit later.

[This article](http://www.actionscripterrors.com/?p=409) mentions that one cause for this error is when you attempt to do something before Flash has had a chance to setup it's "security context".

For example, you can use the `setInterval()` method or a `Timer` object to connect the socket a few (or hundred) milliseconds after startup. Or you could add a button to the screen and only connect after the button is clicked.